# Data is being added in the array but not showing on the UI until reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch

I am posting new data to the backend. It is being sent successfully but the section where I fetched these data are not being updated until I press reload on the browser.

Here I am adding the code. Please let me know where am I making the problem? Thanks a lot.

```
//This is a custom hook where I am fetching data.
  const [products, setProducts] = useProductsHook();

  const handleAddProduct = () => {
    const newProduct = {
      name: productName,
      image: imageLink,
      desc: desc,
      price: +price,
      quantity: +quantity,
      supplier: supplierName,
    };
    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/products", newProduct).then((res) => {
      setProducts(products.concat(res.data));
      setProductName("");
      setImageLink("");
      setDesc("");
      setPrice("");
      setQuantity("");
      setSupplierName("");
    });
  };
```

Comment: Hey buddy, you are referring to the same state object, hence the UI is not refreshing. Try `setProducts([...products.concat(res.data)]`.

Comment: Hi  @TirthTrivedi, Thank you. I have added products to the dependency of my useEffect in Custom Hook and it worked fine. Thanks anyway.